# After hiding a field, Table to Excel gives RuntimeError Cannot find field ''

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, excel, runtimeerror

I'm trying to export a Table View to Excel (using arcpy). It works well if the Table View doesn't have hidden fields. As soon as I hide the OBJECTID when creating the View, I get a runtime error (Cannot find field '').

When I try to do the same in the ModelBuilder, it works. Any idea why the Python script fails to execute?

```
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(TEMP_Consumption, TEMP_Consumption_View, "", "", "OBJECTID OBJECTID HIDDEN NONE;Customer_Name Customer_Name VISIBLE NONE")
arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(TEMP_Consumption_View, ExportFile, "ALIAS", "CODE")
```

The full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\exportconsumptions1.py", line 84, in <module>
arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(TEMP_Consumption_View, ExportFile, "ALIAS", "CODE")
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 81, in TableToExcel
raise e
ExecuteError: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\ArcToolbox\Scripts\TableToExcel.py", line 222, in <module>
arcpy.GetParameter(3))
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\ArcToolbox\Scripts\TableToExcel.py", line 192, in table_to_excel
for row in cursor:
RuntimeError: Cannot find field ''

Failed to execute (TableToExcel).
```

Comment: Just an idea, export your model to python and see if there is any difference in the syntax?

Comment: Please always place the *full* error message, with traceback, in the body of the question, using either a quote block or a code block. Even views should have a rowid column, so hiding it may be the root of your issue.  The question title is a bit deceiving, since it's not just "a field" but "the rowid field".

Comment: @Hornbydd: I tried that and even copied the exported python syntax. It's exactly the same. The only difference is, when building the model it seems it needs something like a refresh before I can use the view for the export to Excel.

Comment: @Vince: I'm aware that the OID is special, but my output Excel file must be without one. Hence the workaround of creating a view (where I can hide fields). It doesn't matter which field is hidden. The error message is the same: If I hide a 'regular' field, I get exactly the same problem. The full error message is:

Comment: Please place critical information **in the question**. It's not fair to those who would answer your question to make them hunt for it in comments.

Comment: @Vince: Noted. Done.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem after renaming fields via arcpy.MakeTableView_management. The adjusted field shows when listing the new table's fields. However when trying to export said table to excel, I receive the same error, "Cannot find field 'xxx'".

Answer (score 1):

I am able to reproduce your issue on ArcGIS 10.4.1. This issue can be reproduced using any other field, so it's not `OBJECTID` specific. My guess is that because you hide a field when creating a table view, it might get misinterpreted by the `Table To Excel` tool and it gets an empty string internally. There are a couple of workarounds:

#### Using external `xlsxwriter` package

I use `xlsxwriter` Python package for all my Excel-generation related operations. It's much more flexible than the `Table To Excel` because it uses `.xlsx` Excel files:

- Number of columns: Table To Excel: 256; xlsxwriter: 16,384
- Number of rows: Table To Excel: 65,536; xlsxwriter: 1,048,576

You can create own styles for cells using `xlsxwriter`, add charts, formulas and many other things. The reason Esri is using the `xlwt` for the Table To Excel tool is most likely because this package comes built-in into the Python installation. Some of the functionality I mention is also possible to implement using `xlwt` but it's a lot of work comparing to `xlsxwriter`.

You can use the `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` for iterating rows as you need and write rows to Excel. Maybe you would like to use another columns order or add some borders. In a word, make a transition to `xlsxwriter` whenever you can.

This is everything it takes to export the rows from a feature class using a `where_clause`:

```
import xlsxwriter
import arcpy

excel_path = r'C:\GIS\out_fc.xlsx'
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(excel_path)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

fc = r"C:\GIS\Temp\ArcGISHomeFolder\Default.gdb\cities"
fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc) if not f.required]

rows = [r for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields, 'POP1990 > 1000000')]
rows_structured = [list(elem) for elem in rows]
rows_structured.insert(0, fields)

for i, row in enumerate(rows_structured):
    worksheet.write_row(i, 0, row)
workbook.close()
```

#### Using the built-in `xlwt` module

However, if you do need to use the `xlwt` built-in module, you may like running the `Table To Excel` Python module on your own to work around the problem with hiding fields. If you print `sys.path` after importing the `arcpy`, you will see that there is a path to `'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.4\\ArcToolBox\\Scripts'`.

The `Table To Excel` geoprocessing tool is just a plain Python module stored there as `TableToExcel.py`. You can just import this file and then call the function to generate the Excel. I am able to create an output Excel `.xls` file without `OBJECTID` using the table view obtained from the `Make Table View` GP tool.

```
import arcpy
import TableToExcel

arcpy.MakeTableView_management(in_table="Database Connections/esrigdb.sde/esrigdb.DBO.Property",
                               out_view="DBO.Property_View",
                               where_clause="", workspace="", field_info="""OBJECTID OBJECTID HIDDEN NONE""")

TableToExcel.table_to_excel(in_table="DBO.Property_View", output=r'C:\GIS\Temp\outHiddenObjId.xls',
                            use_domain_desc=True,use_field_alias=True)
```